# how to make deep method defaults?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm using underscore.js
There is a method called "defaults". But it is not deep. Are there a method which does what _.defaults method does but does it deep? Or maybe somebody can help me how to make such method using _.defaults method?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#defaultsDeep

Comment: thanks, but we use underscore in our project and can not use lodash...

Comment: Time for an upgrade from underscore :). lodash is superset, well maintained and more performant. Whatever underscore supports lodash also supports alias is also `"_"`. So it should be a smooth upgrade.